# setTimeout() doesn't make a transition effect

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a red bar (created with a div and a red background-color) that can extend from 0 pixels in width to 200 pixels in width. My code works when I insert a `window.alert(x.width)` in the function `myF()`, but the code doesn't give me a transition when I don't put it in. Is it just a problem with the `setTimeout()`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function myF(){
          var x = document.getElementById("bar1").style;
            if(parseInt(x.width)<200){
             x.width = (parseInt(x.width)+1)+"px";
             setTimeout(myF(),1);
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="myF()">
      <div id="bar1" style="width:0px; text-align:center; height:10px;background-color:red; font-size:10px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should do :

```
setTimeout(myF,1);
```

instead of :

```
setTimeout(myF(),1);
```

Comment: A little explanation as to why the first is wrong and the second is right might go a long way (I know, but I didn't spot the problem before you did)

Comment: Thank you! That works. But why would the parentheses make such a big difference?

Comment: setTimeout takes a function object as its first parameter. A common mistake is to use myF(), which will use the return value of the call myF and not the actual function myF. This is, most of the time, a silent error, since when the function returns undefined setTimeout will not raise any error.